# Label or font colors on an imagery background examples

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, image, layouts, references

I have been in searching of a website that was done by somebody from ESRI that wrote about...if I remember right...it was in either on the ArcGIS Mapping Center or in the ESRI Technical support article....

There was an article that an author from ESRI wrote about an examples of colors of Labels or font on over a satellite imagery in the background...

Can't remember what it was about the article but I believe it was meant to give the users an examples of colors to show or visualize you the colors with the image in the background.

I had that site saved it to my bookmark back then before ESRI decided to redesign their website and it may have move or remove from their server.

I would like to get that information restore again but I can't find it on the internet...

Anyone remember it?

P.S. I wanted to modify this and add :  This is mean to help my end-user to distinct the colors of the labels on the image backgound and I know ESRI wrote that article..

And one more thing from the Mapbox : https://blog.mapbox.com/designing-labels-for-satellite-and-aerial-imagery-7036163aa21

But it lacks all the different colors...

Comment: If you still have the original url, I occasionally use the wayback time machine https://archive.org/web/ to find 'archived' pages.

Comment: No I don't have that original url...:(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I had to go back and keep searching...I had the old external hard drive I have saved over the years...

I looked at the chrome bookmard I save and found this ...

This is what I have been searching since I move here from New Mexico.

The link to that one is :  https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/mapping/can-you-read-me-now/